# Почему отправка писем с помощью curl является небезопасной

Tags: curl, sendmail

что бы отправить письмо через сервер gmail мне потребовалось настроить свой аккаунт gmail так что бы он позволял небезопасным приложениям использовать его. после этого письмо отправилось, но попало в спам. но с такой же проблемой я столкнулся так же с корпоративной почтой, через которую не удается отправить письмо, хотя с теми же настройками сервера почты(например в ipmi) письма успешно доставляются.

я выполняю следующую команду:

`curl --url "smtp://webmail.avilex.ru:587" --ssl-reqd --mail-from "from@domain" --mail-rcpt "recipient" --upload-file mail.txt --user "user:password"  --insecure`

## содержание файла mail.txt

```
From: "User" <моя почта откуда отправляю>
To: "Jonh" <моя почта куда отправляю>
Subject: hi jonh

Hi John,
I’m sending this mail with curl thru my gmail account.
Bye!
```

## и получаю ошибку

**curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer**

можно ли как то сделать так что бы сервер считал curl безопасным?
или есть еще какие то библиотеки для Си что бы можно было отправлять письма?